# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderWebChat' of undefined

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am creating a web chat which is embedded in an iframe source. What I want is to change the background color of each chat messages (referred to as Chat Bubbles) within that iframe.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="webchat" role="main">
        <iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/...?s=SECRET_KEY_HERE'
        style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

const styleOptions = {
    bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
    bubbleFromUserBackground: '#ddd'
};

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret: 'MY_SECRET_KEY_HERE' }),
    // Passing "styleOptions" when rendering Web Chat
    styleOptions
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
</script>
```

**PROBLEM:**

I am able to see the Iframe and also with the dedicated Secret Key I am able to chat; however, I am not able to see the style applied on chat bubble and on page load I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderWebChat' of undefined

What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work, you are mixing two ways of embedding a web chat.

1. [Embed via iFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
2. [Integrate with JavaScript](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#integrate-with-javascript)

If you want to style your web chat, you would need to use the JavaScript integration. The JavaScript integration has extensive documentation where they show [how to start](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#integrate-with-javascript) and [how to modify the web chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples#samples-list).